# How do I open a pull request containing only the first few commits of the source branch?

Tags: git, tfs, version-control, pull-request, git-flow

I have a TFS git repo which more or less follows gitflow. Three feature branches were reviewed and merged into *develop* then it turned out that the feature which was merged the latest requires additional thinking. None of them were merged into *master* yet.

I'd like to open a pull request into *master* containing only the earliest two features from *develop*. Not "skip the one in the middle" or something, just the two earliest merged in the order they are in the *develop* branch. I'll open a separate PR for the third one later.

However TFS only allows to open a pull request with all the changes. I see no means to select only the start of the commit chain.

I know I can cherry-pick, force-push and all that by of course I'd like to keep *develop* as unchanged as possible.

How do I only have the few earliest unmerged commits included into a TFS git pull request?